# Serial data printing slowly

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, data

I have connected an arduino serial port to my PC and monitoring the output in realterm. I am trying to print:
CR
11.98,123,3520,01CRLF

But it is resulting with some delay. First
CR
1 
Is printed. After sometime, say 0.25sec, the rest of the data (1.98,123,3520,01CRLF) is received. Finally its shown like 
CR
11.98,123,3520,01CRLF

Why is there a delay between CR1 and the rest of the characters when printing using a single serial print!?

Serial.print("\r11.98," +string1+","+string2+",01"\r\n);

string1 & string2 hold data values from 2 separate sensors.

Comment: I will receive sensor values and calculate and store them in the names of string1 & string2. Because the data that i am displaying are in diff data types. So i save them as string and display

Comment: Please include a full working example, that shows this problem in your question.

Comment: Please don't try and concatenate Strings and string literals. It's just nasty. Really nasty. Just print each portion separately.

Comment: For your information, i printed each portion separately. Output mid-delay was there. I changed the code as like the post. Still i got the same...  So i need solution alone...

Comment: You still did not show a full working example. “Full” = something that defines both `setup()` and `loop()` and can be compiled and tested.